# Does Brussels Airlines codeshare (code share) with SAS?

Tags: airlines, code-share

I got caught up in the Brussels Airlines (SN) wave of cancellations. I need to go from ORD to ARN and there is a direct flight on SAS. I am on the phone with Brussels Airlines and they claim they do not code share with SAS.

Given both airlines are part of Star Alliance and that the Internet says SAS and SN do code share, what's the truth?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code sharing and alliances are two different animals.

Code Sharing is when airline A blocks seats on airline B's route from city XYZ to city DEF.  Then sells those seats with airline A's flight number. Airline A may only contract for one code share route with airline B or it may contract for 50 routes.

Airlines can code share with whomever they wish, irregardless of alliances. And they choose the routes they feel match their marketing goals and customer's needs.

Alliances revolve more around joint marketing of all members, plus convenice of connecting travelers with fellow alliance members.  And while alliance members frequently code share with each other, the majority of flights are exclusive to the operating carrier.

Answer (score 7):

Surely the relevant question is whether or not they codeshare *on that route*? And they don't: in fact, Brussels Airlines' website won't let you buy tickets to Stockholm Arlanda (ARN) at all. They only operate routes, codeshare or otherwise, into Stockholm Bromma (BMA).